# How to install a virtual machine on a different physical hard drive using VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

As the title states, I'm looking to install a Virtual Machine on a different physical Hard Drive using VirtualBox..

I don't know how to do it though. I can't find any place in the installation process that lets me pick a different hard drive.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question was asked 2 years and 7 months ago.  Now, in July 2017, it prompts for the install location during the installation process.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Change default storage path

From the VirtualBox Manager we can define the default location of Virtual Machines by choosing a location path, which can also be on a different drive if this drive was mounted with r/w permissions:

[image]

#### Create a VDI on a different path

If that drive is not for general use we can also create a virtual drive we had stored on a different path (click on [image]):

[image]

#### Load a VDI to an existing VM

Any VDI located on a different drive can also be attached to a virtual machine on the machine's storage settings. Click on [image] then *choose a virtual hard disk file* on any path of mounted drives.

#### Caveats

To avoid an error when starting a virtual machine we have to take care to **Always** mount the drive holding our VDIs before we start Virtual Box.

Answer (score 2):

Open virtual box ..

1) click new

2) choose OS

3)Memory size

4) Create a vertual hard drive now

5) choose type (VDI)

6) Dynamic allocated

7) File location and size

first mount the destination partition (Just open it on nautilus)

press on folder icon and choose your location

check this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/HFRbU.jpg

Comment: I understood up to point 7. I hadn't seen the folder icon up until now, so thanks for that. I don't understand the "... press on computer on left pane >> then press on /" bla bla bit.. I can just pick my second hard-drive, can I not?

Comment: Go ahead , that's not available in my PC ....

Comment: Please, see my edit :D

Comment: 1) choose the answer to mark it as the right answer 

2) ask another question with more info

Answer (score 0):

Once you create the Virtual machine all you have to do is copy or cut it to the different drive.

Comment: upvoted because it gives another solution for already created images